# Comparar con if en objetos de objetos JS

Tags: javascript

Necesito alguna ayuda pero simplemente no logro encontrar la manera de solucionar esa pequeña duda que tengo, estoy tratando de hacer una comparación para sacar true/false de un Objeto en JavaScript por ejemplo tengo ese resultado en la consola de Chrome:

```
{sortBy: "price_asc"}
```

Tomando en cuenta de que la variable es un objeto pero como puedo sacar de esa variable que el valor es `"price_asc" = true`, intente con [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) pero me regresa `["sortBy"]`

Hay alguna manera de sacar en el if por ejemplo:

```
if (Object.keys(this.searchParams) === 'price_asc') {
    return null;
}
```

Se agradece si alguien me puede aclarar esa duda.

Comment: `if (this.searchParams.sortBy === 'price_asc') {`

Comment: en lo personal no entendí nada de lo que escribiste, según el título de la pregunta tu tienes un objeto que posee objetos entonces tienes algo parecido a esto -> `var objeto = { objetoInterno: { sortBy: "price_asc" } }` ?? en ese caso puedes acceder al valor de *sortBy* así: `objeto.objetoInterno.sortBy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así usando el `.`:

```js
var obj = {sortBy: "price_asc"}

if(obj.sortBy === "price_asc"){
console.log("si, es price_asc")
}
```

ó usando `[]`

```js
var obj = {sortBy: "price_asc"}

var key = "sortBy"

    if(obj[key] === "price_asc"){
    console.log("si, es price_asc")
    }
```

ó usando `Object.values`

```js
var obj = {sortBy: "price_asc"}

if(Object.values(obj)[0] === "price_asc"){
console.log("si, es price_asc")
}
```

Si quieres iterar, pueder usar `for in`:

```js
var obj = {sortBy: "price_asc"}

for(key in obj){
    console.log(key)
    console.log(obj[key])
}
```

si el objeto es `this.searchParams` sería `this.searchParams.sortBy`